# If a Jew visits a mosque and offers a prayer to "Allah", which commandments are being violated?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, islam

If a Jew visits a mosque and offers a prayer to "Allah" as a good-will gesture, which commandments are being violated? What are the views of the Jewish Sages on this type of interfaith cross-pollination?

Comment: Related: the comments on http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1432

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26328/759

Comment: What kind of prayer? "Allah" is the same as our God, and just praying to God isn't an issue.

Comment: This looks like  dupe of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26328/759