# May one park in a Church across the road which charges a daily parking fee?

Tags: halacha, christianity, vehicles-transportation

Is it permitted to park in a church which charges a daily fee for use of its parking lot?

Possible concerns might be:

- Someone who knows the owner's car may think he has gone in to worship.
- The money paid for parking may be used to support evangelism against Jews.
- If the religion is classified as Avodah Zarah, the money may be supporting Avodah Zarah.

Comment: Would not charging be better? Youre still using it.

Comment: You should include what might be wrong, such as ma'aris ayin (as an example)

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1432/getting-benefit-from-a-church

Comment: @DoubleAA my question was based on having benefit from a Church (although I did not specify that). I added the charging part as perhaps there is less benefit when paying then when using a Church for free.

Answer (score 4):

[Torah Tavlin - January 17, 2015](http://www.kbaforshay.com/PDF/Torah%20Tavlin%20-%2075/13-Vaera.pdf) Drush V'Chiddush column - quoting Rabbi David Feinstein Shlita says it is forbidden to park in a church parking lot. The reason is since a Jew would have to duck down to enter their car, it would give an impression that they are bowing to the crucifix.

Comment: What if the car is positioned with the door away from the crucifix?

Comment: I would have to ask Rabbi David Feinstein. I imagine he would say there is no difference as people will come to park in a way that is a problem, not differentiating where the crucifix is.

Comment: Note that the R'DF was speaking (according to that column) about a church that has a crucifix on the outside [presumably visible from wherever the car is]. Presumably he'd not forbid (or not forbid for that reason at least) parking on a side of the church building from which no crucifix can be seen.

Comment: Why didn't you post the Rama as an answer

Answer (score 1):

The Rama in Yoreh Deah 149:2 (as pointed out by Gershon Gold) discusses cutting through a courtyard of a house of worship. He writes that when they get together to worship it is always forbidden to pass through the courtyard to get to another place. However,if it is not during a time of gathering (worship ) then one can pass through to get to another place. There is a middas chassidas not to pass through even though it mutar,but if it is the fastest route then it's fine.

I would speculate that in your case which is  about parking a car in the lot may be for a long period and  passersbys may recognize your car and it would be a problem of maaryis ayin.

Comment: You might get more upvotes if you would [edit] your post to improve its spelling, grammar, punctuation, and clarity.  (I upvoted your post anyway, since it was at zero.)